# Why won't this MVC Route Work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes defined in my RouteConfig class:

```
       routes.MapRoute(
             name: "DefaultMessage",
             url: "API/{action}",
             defaults: new { action = "MessageGateway" }
         ); 
        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "DefaultNoParms",
              url: "{controller}/{action}",
              defaults: new { controller = "API", action = "Login" }
         );
```

When I test this on my localhost with just localhost:65133/ as the address I am routed to the Login ActionResult on the APIController, but when I try localhost:65133/API I get the following error:

> The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which
>   is required

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? The ActionResult MessageGateway does exist...

Comment: While not answering your question. Look into AttributeRouting.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like the error is self-explanatory - you need to tell it what controller to go to.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultMessage",
    url: "API/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "API", action = "MessageGateway" }
);
```

Comment: Yeah, specifically, the error is you didn't specify a controller in either the defaults or in the route to.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I assumed that "API/" would do that.

Comment: OK. That got me part of the way there... but now when I add this route (API/apilogin), it doesn't recognize it:  

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "APILogin",
        url: "API/apilogin",
        defaults: new { controller = "API", action = "apilogin" }
    ); 

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaultMessage",
        url: "API/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "API", action = "MessageGateway" }
    ); 

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaultNoParms",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "API", action = "Login" }
);

Comment: I just tried putting those in, and it worked perfectly. `/` took me to `APIController.Login()`, `/API` took me to `APIController.MessageGateway()`, `/API/Foo` took me to `APIController.Foo()`, `/API/apilogin` took me to `APIController.apilogin()`. What problem are you seeing?